# Upgraded Samsung device to Android 12, but Quick Panel still looks like the last Android version

Tags: samsung, quick-settings, android-12

After updating Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra to Android 12, I expected the Quick Panel to look completely different like I seen in some Android 12 reviews.
But my Quick Panel looks exactly the same as before the upgrade.

[image]

The About Phone says: One UI 4, Android 12

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: Only Google Pixel devices and Android One devices are getting plain AOSP version. Other manufacturer are usually not so stupid to take over changes nearly everybody dislikes like new quick settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

The looks of your UI are completely dependent on your software provider, in this case: stock (Samsung). So, no matter what Android version you are running, if the UI version is the same, the looks will be the same too.

So let's say your device has One UI version 4. Even if you were to get an Android 13 update (hypothetical) and the One UI version remains 4, your device UI would be exactly the same as the one you have right now.

Comment: Makes sense  thank!

Comment: No Problemo mate.